# Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory) in amazon-s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have application which is deployed to heroku using amazon s3 posting images to buckets.This works perfectly fine. But when fetching same image it gives error:

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory showing path s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/app/public/messages/images/000/000/061/thumb/images.jpeg?1362410115)
```

Same path copying and pasting in browser's url doesn't work. If I am using bucket name as end point it works ie, with following path

```
/bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/app/public/messages/images/000/000/061/thumb/images.jpeg?1362410115.
```

But I dont know how to configure this url in my model. I am following heroku's way to configure aws-sdk.

```
 https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3
```

Model has_attached_file seems like i am missing something here.For rest of configuration you can check above link.

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "100x100>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
```

Thanks

Comment: For others, I received this error message when I was trying to copy a file from S3 and it had 0 bytes. Check the `content_length` of the S3 Object to see if that's your issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including given code in config/initializers/paper_clip.rb resolved my problem.

```
    Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!(
        :url => ':s3_domain_url',
        :path => 'app/public/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
    )
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Am I supposed to have anything else in that file? I just copied and pasted the code snippet from above.

Comment: Thiw worked for me as well. It didn't work at first, but that's because I didn't upload a new image, and allow for it to work.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!! this is what I want! works perfectly and justified my wasted time looking for a solution. Regards.