# Heroku rails s3 switching end point url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm able to save photos, but when I use image_tag, I get this url.

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/{bucket}/users/avatars/000/000/001/thumb/{pic}.png?1372135035
```

when what I want is

```
http://{bucket}/s3.amazonaws.com/users/avatars/000/000/001/thumb/{pic}.png?1372135035
```

This seems like it should be simple to solve, but I haven't found it yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this link out, hope this will help you.

[Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory) in amazon-s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220428/errnoenoent-no-such-file-or-directory-in-amazon-s3/15230551#15230551)

Comment: I used this example, but with no effect. It's still giving me the same incorrect link via image_tag.

Comment: Nice find. Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
#{bucket}/s3.amazonaws.com/users/avatars/000/000/001/thumb/#{pic}.png?1372135035
```